# wait_for and condition Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I somehow wrote this code that allows only one writer at a time and there can't be readers while the writer is working. It works, but I don't know why, I understood that for `wait_for()` to wake up it was necessary to call `notify()` but I didn't and still works.

Thanks!

```
import threading
import time

condition = threading.Condition()

def test():
    return True

def reader(data):
    with condition:
        condition.wait_for(test)
    print('read')

def writer(data):
    with condition:
        time.sleep(5)
    print('write')

def runThread(data):
    if data["w"]: #writer
        writer(data)
    elif data["r"]: #reader
        reader(data)

def run():
    #something happens
    threading.Thread(target=runThread, daemon=True, ).start()
```

Comment: From the library doc, `wait_for: Wait until a condition evaluates to True`. I believe you are referring to `wait` which indeed needs to be notified. `wait: Wait until notified or until a timeout occurs`

Comment: @NicLaforge maybe I'm not sure, but if you're right now I don't know why it stops working if I remove `with condition` from`writer(data)`

Comment: The condition implement a context manager. Using with will call enter/exist. Enter prior running the code within the with statement then on exit it will call the exist method.
    ```def __enter__(self):
        return self._lock.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return self._lock.__exit__(*args)```